# How to fix these weird triangles and artifacts in texturing?

Tags: texturing

when in applied an image texture I got these super weird texture glitches or whatever they are. please help me! (i am using an ANT landscape with a subdivison modifier on if that helps)
[image]

Comment: can you please share your file via https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Such problems with ANT and texturing usually come from the unwrapping process. Don't use projections, just Edit mode -> UV -> Unwrap. That should do the trick.